# Cambiar nombre de la Ventana de un JOptionPane

Tags: java

tengo una duda: ¿Cómo hago para cambiar el nombre de la ventana de un  JOptionPane.showInputDialog ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En lugar de que me aparezca Entrada quiero ponerle "OPERACIONES ARITMETICAS"

```
`public class Punto_3 
{       
    public static void main(String[] args)           
    {
        try 
        {   
            int operacion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese una opcion \n" 
                                                                    + "1-Conversion \n"
                                                                    + "2-Suma \n" 
                                                                    + "3-Resta \n" 
                                                                    + "4-Multiplicacion \n"
                                                                    + "5-Division \n"));
            
            iniciarMenu(operacion);
        } `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `showInputDialog` viene con un parámetro llamado `title`, en el que puedes editar dicha función, el parámetro viene en un `constructor`, donde

```
showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                     Object message,
                     String title,
                     int messageType)
```

el tercer parámetro es el que tienes que editar

Entonces tu código quedaría

```
int operacion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese una opcion \n" 
                                                                    + "1-Conversion \n"
                                                                    + "2-Suma \n" 
                                                                    + "3-Resta \n" 
                                                                    + "4-Multiplicacion \n"
                                                                    + "5-Division \n", "OPERACIONES ARIMÉTICAS", JoptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
```

El 4 parametro es el que te puede causar un poco de confusión, en este caso todos los int son constantes de la clase `JOptionPane` y pueden ser

```
ERROR_MESSAGE, INFORMATION_MESSAGE, WARNING_MESSAGE, QUESTION_MESSAGE, or PLAIN_MESSAGE
```

Para más información puedes revisar la [Documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)